# Unable to install namerctl

Tags: linkerd

I have the following version of go on my ubuntu, I am unable to install namerd, Please find the image below.

go version go1.6 linux/amd64

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `go get -u github.com/linkerd/namerctl` will install the executable into your `$GOPATH/bin` directory. You need to make sure that directory is included in your shell's `$PATH` in order to use namerctl from the command line.

Comment: ls -l $GOPATH/bin/namerctl

that helped me find where the namerctl is !! thank you @klingerf

Comment: Added this path to export PATH=$PATH:/root/go_workspace/bin to my env (note: source ~/.profile to refresh)